# How do we got 50 points so that we post comments?

Tags: discussion

I tried to post a comment, but it said that I need 50 points to post a comment. How do we get points?

Comment: Answer questions, gain reputation by people upvoting your answers, see here http://travel.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 6):

I think you'll find our [tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) page answers all your questions.  Basically, ask questions, post good answers, and as people upvote your posts, you'll get to 50 points really fast.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how to earn reputation see *[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)* in the [help center](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help).